# Can you wrap schema.org markup in <p> tags?

Tags: html, microdata, schema.org

I’m implementing schema.org markup on a contact page on a website to structure the bussiness name, address, phone number and email.

To format it I’ve wrapped parts of it in `<p>` tags. Will this invalidate the schema.org markup?

Here is what it looked like before the `p` tags:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
<span itemprop="name">Acne co</span>
<div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
 <span itemprop="streetAddress">123 street</span>
 <span itemprop="addressLocality">London</span>,
 <span itemprop="addressRegion"></span>
 <span itemprop="postalCode">N64TF</span>
   </div>
   <span itemprop="telephone">02083548800</span>
   <span itemprop="email">studio@acne.co.uk</span>
</div>
```

and here is what it looks like after:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness"> 
<p class="title">
     <span itemprop="name">Acne co</span>
   </p>

     <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
   <p>
     <span itemprop="streetAddress">123 street</span><br />
     <span itemprop="addressLocality">London</span>, <span itemprop="postalCode">N64TF</span>
   </p>
   </div>

   <p>
   <span itemprop="telephone">02083548800</span><br />
   <span itemprop="email">studio@acne.co.uk</span>
   </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the Microdata specification gives examples which have the same structure of `<span>` tags nested inside `<p>` tags.

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-microdata-20110405/#the-basic-syntax